# Loop issues not continuing the continue loop in owl carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I've added the script for the owl carousel but the script is not working for continuous loop, below is my code

```
  var owl = $("#owl-demo-2");
  owl.owlCarousel({
      items : 1, 
  infinite: true,
    loop: true,
      itemsDesktop : [992,1],
      itemsDesktopSmall : [768,1], 
      itemsTablet: [480,1],    
      itemsMobile : [320,1]
  });
```

The loop: true doesn't work

Comment: check this link `https://codepen.io/divinector/pen/MRxMMy`

Comment: Not working the above script is working fine only the loop true is not working